# Unable to lookup on methodHandles from JNI

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

In my C++ JNI code I want to invoke the following method.but I am getting NullPointerException.

```
MethodHandles.Lookup handle=MethodHandles.lookup();
```

The following approach I am using for invoking lookup method.

```
 jclass methodHandlesClassId = env->FindClass("java/lang/invoke/MethodHandles");
if(methodHandlesClassId != nullptr){
    jmethodID lookupMethodId = env->GetStaticMethodID(methodHandlesClassId, "lookup", "()Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodHandles$Lookup;");
    if(lookupMethodId != nullptr){
        jobject handleObj = (jobject) env->CallStaticObjectMethod(methodHandlesClassId, lookupMethodId);
    }
}
```

Please Help ?

Comment: Where exactly do you get the `NullPointerException`?

Comment: after invoking env->CallStaticObjectMethod(....) my handleObj is null. I called env.ExceptionDescribe() after this method call,and came to know about exception.